# Is there a way to attach an event handler to a drawer opening and closing?

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I'm working on a game for my son and I would like the game to pause automatically when the drawer is opened. In order to accomplish that, I want to associate a `dispatch()` call to the drawer opening event.

Comment: Are you using Vue 1? [dispatch is replaced in Vue 2](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced)

Comment: I am using Vue 2

Comment: Is the drawer a widget your game owns, or a built-in feature of the browser? Can you give at least a sketch of your code structure?

Comment: sorry, I should have provided more details. I am using Quasar Framework's drawer component.

Comment: Maybe handle `@focus` on the `q-drawer`?

Comment: Didn't work, but I figured out an answer which works... On the `button` for the hamburger menu, I attached a method which not only toggles the drawer open, but it also pauses the game.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lifecycle methods `beforeUpdate` and `update` https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/ because you cannot listen to the native rendering cycles of a browser. So you can pause when vue does DOM updates but the browser maybe does more, for instance because of a css-animation.

Another features of the vue- lifecycle is that it works as a queue for update events.

Comment: This would be OK if I didn't have a bunch of other stuff updating the Dom on a regular basis.